# How to send bitcoins

Tags: transactions

I bought a small amount of BTC. They are sitting in an online wallet. I would like to send them to my blockchaininfo wallet. Is this the process? 
1. Enter the amount to send.
2. Copy/paste the receiving address.
3. Send. 
Do I need to do anything with private keys at the sending or receiving end of the process? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your steps sound just fine. You won't need to worry about the private keys at the back end as your online wallet stores these keys for you (and uses them to create the transaction to move the coins from one wallet to another).

Hopefully it goes without saying that you should store your blockchain.info wallet private keys somewhere as well just in case you somehow lose access to blockchain.info.

Comment: When you say "back end", I'm assuming you are referring to the online wallet I am sending from?

Comment: Your second tip says I should store my blockchaininfo wallet private keys somewhere. Could you elaborate on that point since I'm not sure what you mean.  Thanks for your help. I probably should have researched BTC more before buying, but it is what it is. For now I want to get them into a more secure wallet as soon as possible. Then I'll get back to learning how to do everything else. Thanks and if anyone else has anything they'd like to add, please do.